# Recommended Notebook and Cell Options for Deployed GUIs

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction

I often use `CreateNotebook` to enclose GUIs that open in a `Deployed`, non `Saveable` and non `Editable` `Notebook`.  I want these GUIs to be as efficient as possible on Kernel performance and managing memory.  In summary, I don't want to allow the FrontEnd the possibility of any distraction trying to do anything but evaluating and allowing the manipulation of what's contained in the output Cell(s).  These are GUIs that are created every time they will be used, so there is no need to select cells or specific content, modify or save the notebook containing the GUI, etc. As examples I'm showing these possible initial settings for those notebooks:

---

`CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "ShowPredictiveInterface"] = False;
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"FileOutlineCache" -> False};
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "SeTrackCellChangeTimes" -> False];`

---

Can you help adding other desirable Notebook and Cell options that can help save memory and improve overall performance of GUIs?  I think that the best way to answer this question is creating a function (similar to `CDFDeploy`), CreateDeployedNotebook (or so) with editable Options like "ShowPredictiveInterface", "AllowInternet", etc.

Comment: Look at the options on `"Dialog.nb"` (you can get it like ``FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["Dialog.nb", "StyleSheetPath"]``). That's probably the most comprehensive set of options. Also be careful with ``FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath`` as using a bad second argument will crash the front end. The one I just gave you is fine though.

Comment: @b3m2a1: Very nice and long list.  Still it would be great if we had a selection of those more critical for the purposes I highlight in my question.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda, why are you disabling the file outline cache?

Comment: @ihojnicki: I don't have a strong justification for any of the examples I provided as I really don't know all the implications of these setting.  That's why I posted the question.  Do you think it should remain enabled?  Why?

Comment: @ArielSepulveda, setting `FileOutlineCache->False` disables some optimizations when loading the file from disk.  Unless you have a really good reason to disable it, it should be left on.

Comment: And if you are setting `Deployed->True` on the notebook, setting `ShowPredictiveInterface` is not required.  Doesn't hurt anything either...

Comment: @ihojnicki: If, as I sated, the Notebook has the option Saveable->False, then 1) what value adds setting FileOutlineCache->True? and 2) what is the 'cost' of keeping it on?  I don't want any processing beyond what is strictly necessary to manipulate and evaluate the output cells.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda: There is no need to set it at all.  Having a file outline cache can potentially reduce the amount of work the FE has to do when loading the document.  Disabling it causes the entire contents to parsed up front.